# Delphi opencv ocvFFMpegIPCamSource to a bitmap?

Tags: opencv, delphi, ffmpeg, pascal

There is a way to a capture/convert ocvFFMpegIPCamSource stream to a bitmap?

First I try to do this:

```
FrameBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
FrameBitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;

Image5.Picture.Graphic := IplImage2Bitmap(ocvView1.Image, FrameBitmap);
```

// Image5 is my bitmap.

Obviously is geting a error, because "**ocvView1.Image**" is of type  "**IocvImage**" and the first parameter of the function **IplImage2Bitmap** needs a type "**pIpIImage**"

I missed something in the middle of the process..

Second i try using "**cvImage2Bitmap**":

```
FrameBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
FrameBitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;

Image5.Picture.Graphic := cvImage2Bitmap(ocvView1.Image, FrameBitmap);
```

Again, needs a type "**pIpIImage**" and i am trying to pass a "**IocvImage**"

I cannot see what is missing.

There is a way to make this conversion?

I need to do this directly from **ocvFFMpegIPCamSource** component, or from **ocvView** component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see in sources:

```
IocvImage = interface
...
property IpImage: pIplImage Read GetIplImage;
```

so you have to use `ocvView1.Image.IpImage`